# I want to make a HTML table scrollabe in a unique way

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, html-table

I want to implement a **html table**.  This is the screen shot.

[image]

The first line Categories is **static**. In the second line, the first column is static (date and images), but the second column of times and channels should be **scrollable**.

There will be 24 columns, times with half an hour interval. And only that portion should be scrollable. Any ideas how I can achieve that?

**This is my current code but it is no way near to what i want.**

```
<table width="100%" class="guide-table" BORDER=10 BORDERCOLOR="#EEEEEE" BORDERCOLORLIGHT="#EEEEEE" BORDERCOLORDARK="#EEEEEE">
<tr>
<td>Fri, 25 Sep</td>
<td>4:30 PM</td>
<td>5:00 PM</td>
<td>5:30 PM</td>
<td>6:00 PM</td>
<td>6:30 PM</td>
<td>4:30 PM</td>
<td>5:00 PM</td>
<td>5:30 PM</td>
<td>6:00 PM</td>
<td>6:30 PM</td>
<td>4:30 PM</td>
<td>5:00 PM</td>
<td>5:30 PM</td>
<td>6:00 PM</td>
<td>6:30 PM</td>
<td>4:30 PM</td>
<td>5:00 PM</td>
<td>5:30 PM</td>
<td>6:00 PM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="https://iprx.ten.com.au/ImageHandler.ashx?w=250&h=140&f=jpg&u=https%3A%2F%2Fnetworkten-a.akamaihd.net%2Fnew%2F2199827728001%2F201612%2F86%2F2199827728001_5239789882001_5239788195001-vs.jpg%3FpubId%3D2199827728001" height="35px" width="75px"></td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
<td>Ten News</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What did you tried? Post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a plugin dataTable which provides features like FixedColumn and FixedHeader using which your intended purpose can be solved.

https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/

https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/

Answer (score 0):

Use one column for your content Part (colspan/rowspan) and nest a scrollable div with the second table with the 24 columns in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had to code this exact interface. There is nothing out there which does what you are looking for, essentially three nested tables all independantly scrollable in fixed directions. Trust me... I've looked.

I have hand coded a solution that can be found [here](http://ibios.co.uk/preview). It's a technology preview that I prepared to demonstrate this feature. Click the burger button in the top left, then select "Guest Rooms" from the menu. The scrolling table is to the right. Use left / right arrow keys to scroll horizontally. I had to do this as the top row is dates, so is infinitely scrollable.

If you inspect this you should be able to get an idea of the problems involved... It's not a trivial bit of code, which is why I've not posted it here.